# how to send string as file in c++ (webassembly) function as argument from javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a function in c++ that takes a file as an argument in main function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        auto len = std::strlen(argv[1]);
        if (len >= 4 && argv[1][len-1] == 'c' && argv[1][len-2] == 'n' && argv[1][len-3] == '.') {
            read_file(argv[1]);
            save_all_lines();

        } else {
            std::fprintf(stderr, "ncc: " BOLD_RED "error" NORMAL ": unknown file format. Only files with extension 'nc' are supported\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "usage: ncc FILE\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

}
```

I have compiled this c++ program into webassembly. I want to type a string in browser textarea which will be sent to the main function as an argument.

I have turned the string into a blob() then that blob object into a file but how should i send the file in the webassembly function.

```
#EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION
            var contents = `
                func main(){
                    print("hello");
                }
            `;
            var blob = new Blob([contents], { type: "text/plain" });
            var file = new File([blob], "test.nc", { type: "text/plain" });
    
            var data = new Uint8Array(file);
    
            Module._main(2, data);
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if webassembly security / browser security will let you load files. Chrome has the most functionality for loading files from the FS, but even in Chrome you cannot activate this functionality without a user click (plus security warnings)

Comment: ... But I have been completely wrong making assumptions like this before :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Emscripten, you need to "mount" your `File` object into the emulated filesystem using [`FS.mount`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#FS.mount) method on the JS side.

E.g., assuming the default `MEMFS` filesystem emulation type (where everything is just in memory), the example would look like:

```js
FS.mount(MEMFS, { files: [file /* this is your File object */] }, '/');
```

Then you can access this file on the C++ side under corresponding filename, e.g. in your case `/test.nc`.

Check out the linked docs for more details.